# Divide or Divide it Up: Which is correct in the following context?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

They **divided the money up** among their three children.

They **divided the money**  among their three children.

Is there anything wrong in my second sentence?!!

Comment: Your version (without ***up***) is fine, as would be *They divided **up** the money among their three children*. Personally I'd prefer ***between*** rather than ***among[st]*** - but again, these are stylistic choices with no effect on meaning.

Comment: Both are fine.  I believe that the second is more grammatically correct.

Comment: Actually @FumbleFingers is right, "divided up the money" is better than "divided the money up".  Is the latter a split infinitive?

Comment: @Max: I'm intrigued. On what possible grounds could "more grammatically correct" apply to this situation? I realize some people still *know* about that stupid "split infinitive" business, but it was always spurious, and always something up with which native speakers would not put.

Comment: My feeling was that "divided the money up" (and in fact, "divided up the money") is incorrect, or at least "not as correct", because to "divide up" is a colloqualism, rather than a genuine verb (unlike 'divide').  To illustrate this, what is the difference between "dividing" and "dividing up", and if there's no difference, then why say "dividing up"?

Comment: @Max: It's quite normal to put the object *between* the two components of a phrasal verb, except if it's a *pronoun* (i.e. - you can't say *They divided up **it** among the children*).

Comment: I know it's normal.  Read my first comment again.  I was just saying i thought the second one was better.

Comment: The ultimate test of grammatical correctness is whether or not "Mrs. G." would have whacked you with her Westcott ruler if you wrote it.  In both of these instances, she would not.

Comment: @Max Williams 'Both are fine. I believe that the second is more grammatically correct.' doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FF3: Unless you're using 'phrasal verb' in a restricted sense, this depends on the verb. Some MWVs are optionally, some mandatorily, and some non-separable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth when i say "fine" i mean "acceptable".  You don't think that it's possible for two things to be acceptable, while one of them is better than the other?

Comment: When I say 'fine' I mean 'of very high quality; very good of its kind.
"this was a fine piece of film-making" , excellent, first-class, first-rate, great, exceptional, outstanding, admirable, quality, superior, splendid, magnificent, beautiful, exquisite, choice, select, prime, supreme, superb, wonderful, sublime, superlative, very good, of high quality, of a high standard, second to none, top'. [[Dictionary formerly known as Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=po7QVLS-GJHj8weS2ICYBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=fine+meaning)]. / Quirk ... have written an article on acceptability levels.

Comment: "fine" is also often used to mean "acceptable": for example the first definition here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fine which is "satisfactory" (which hopefully you would agree is synonymous with "acceptable" in this context).  Either way, it seems you misunderstood my point, and perhaps this was due to my choice of words.  If so I apologise for my part in this pointless and overly long quibble.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, Fumblefingers, Edwin, The reason that *divided up the money* seems preferable to *divided the money up* is that when we have "separable phrasal verbs" we prefer to put the Object after the preposition if it is at all long and before it if it is very short. So *put the cat out* is fine but *put the cat that is sitting in the kitchen out* is not so good. *divide the money up* is just one syllable too long to be very good.